# How can I kick out the longest inactive user from a remote machine using powershell 1?

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I need to find an easy way to kick off teammates from a server if they forget to log out. Our terminal service has a limit of 2 connections. I wrote the following function to get the logged in users. As I understand in powershell 2 there are nicer ways to do this but I am stuck with version 1 for now.

The following function will get me the logins per server. (If you know a prettier way to do this feel free to educate me. :) I am not happy with the func and hoping learn a few tricks from you.)

```
function get-terminal-users($serverName)
{
    $path = "C:\ntui\source\i386"

    cd -path $path

    $result = invoke-expression -Command ".\quser.exe /SERVER:$serverName" | select -Skip 1       

    $a = @()

    foreach($row in $result)
    {        
        $d = new-object Object
        $columns = $row.Replace("  ", " ").Split(" ") | ? {$_ -ne ""}    

        $d | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name UserName -value $columns[0]    
        $id = -1
        $sessionName = ""                                  
        $columShift = 0

        #this part was not ok and needed fixing. Thanks Winfred for the answer!
        if([system.int32]::tryparse($columns[1].ToString(),[ref] $id))
        {     
            $columShift --              
        }
        else
        {            
            $sessionName =  $columns[1]
            $id = [system.int32]::parse($columns[2].ToString())                                             
        }          

        $time = [DateTime]::Parse($columns[5 + $columShift] + " " + $columns[6 + $columShift])

        $d | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name SessionName -value $sessionName
        $d | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name ID -value $id     
        $d | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name State -value $columns[3 + $columShift]
        $d | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name Idle -value $columns[4 + $columShift]
        $d | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name Time -value $time 

        $a += $d
    }

    return $a
}
```

So I need the list if users and then I have to kick one guy out if the connection count is higher than the allowed maximum. If you know a way to get this info from the server I would really appreciate your help.

```
$name = "myserver"
$maxConnections = 2

$users = get-terminal-users($name)   

if($users.Count -eq $maxConnections)
{
    $idList = $users | ? { $_.State -eq "Disc" } | select -First 1 | foreach { $_.ID }   

    foreach($id in $idList)
    {          
        invoke-expression -Command ".\logoff.exe /SERVER:$name $id -V"                  
    }
}
```

The issue is that I can only interact with Active connections. Abandoned connections are still use up the available connections and I don't seem to be able to do much about them. A user with a Disc status seems to use up a terminal connection and when I call logoff on its id for some reason a local process is terminated. Is there a way to get rid of Disc connections?

rwinsta.exe also seems to only work with active connections.

I am running the script on XP and targeting a Win 2003 server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the $id incorrectly to the custom object at this line:

```
$d | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name ID -value $id
```

Disconnected sessions don't have a session name see:

```
quser.exe /SERVER:mycomputer
USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
winfred                                   2  Disc      4+21:05  2/28/2012 8:38 AM
```

And require the $columShift, which you have on all your properties, except on the ID Noteproperty. Because of that, you specify the ID incorrectly to logoff.exe, when you are trying to log off a disconnected session.

Instead that line should be:

```
$d | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name ID -value $columns[2 + $columShift]
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. You were right; the id was parsed incorrectly. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Why do this with PowerShell? Use the right tool for the job. In this case, that would be Group Policy.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/winserverTS/thread/620e7bbf-c49b-4ab4-98ab-98e2ce5e979f

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. According the thread you recommended TS Config (RDS Config) can be managed programmatically via Powershell in Windows 2008 R2. The discussion is mostly about setting the session timeout limit.